# Recommendation for a Strategy Game Engine for .NET?

Tags: .net, game-engine

Can anyone recommend a strategy game engine for the .net framework. I downloaded XNA, but it is way beyond my needs. I just want to create a turn based strategy game. I have searched and searched, but all I cannnot find any examples. I have asked for something similiar before, but have not gotten any good answers.

Comment: 3D? 2D? platform? board-like?

Comment: "I just want to create a turn based strategy game." I don't think you'll even find something that will allow you to "just" create a game, unless it is extremely limited. A game is usually a very complex piece of software, even the simpler ones. You might want to adjust your expectations.

Comment: Certainly seems like there could be some better options Fred...let me know if you find anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that XNA doesn't do what yo want, [TorqueX 2D](http://www.torquepowered.com/products/torquex-2d) looks like the closest you will come to an out-of-the-box solution for .NET.

If the problem is that XNA is overkill for your needs, feel free to ignore overly complicated features and work at a lower level of abstraction. For example, I recall that lots of the XNA API mirrors DirectX.

Comment: It is hard to know what is complicated. There is no tutorials on how to do this.